# How to add customized button to opencart

Tags: button, opencart

I'm using opencart for a webstore that I'm developing at the moment and I want to add new button which would display price of the product, just above "Add to Cart" button.

It should look like this button i have styled in photoshop

[image]

Well if you look at the picture, it doesn't even have to be a button, it just needs to like close to that.

Can somebody point me in right direction?

PS: "V Košarico" = "Add To Cart"

This is product/product.tpl code

```
<div class="button-group">
        <!--PRICE BUTTON--!>
          <button type="button">test</button>
          <!--OTHER BUTTONS!-->
          <button type="button" onclick="cart.add('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>', '<?php echo $product['minimum']; ?>');"><span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md"><?php echo $button_cart; ?></span> <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i></button>
          <button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_wishlist; ?>" onclick="wishlist.add('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>');"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></button>
          <button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_compare; ?>" onclick="compare.add('<?php echo $product['product_id']; ?>');"><i class="fa fa-exchange"></i></button>
        </div>
```

Comment: Which part are you having problems with? The styling? Getting the price? Finding the correct file to edit?

Comment: @rjdown i think i have found the correct file to edit (product.tpl) but when i add new button, nothing happens. So i'm having all kind of troubles.

Comment: You're going to need to show what you've done so far, so we can see what you might be doing wrong

Comment: @rjdown can u please check updated code. haven't done, but i have no idea why button doesnt show...even if i copy any of the code above and multipy it by two...i dont get more buttons on my website...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Opencart but if you're talking pure html/css then this is, as you say, a point in the right direction.

Product HTML example

```
<div class="product">

    <div class="description">
        Description text for the product
    </div>

    <div class="price">
        CENA: 5,95 €
    </div>

    <div class="add-to-cart">
        Add to Cart
    </div>

</div>
```

And then the CSS to match it up and especially the .product > .price styling then. Hopefully you know a bit of CSS and can manage the rest yourself? And I'm not sure the product "box" has the same structure or anything of course. But as you say, a point towards the right direction.

```
.product {
   width:300px;
   border:1px solid #aaa;
}

.product > .description {
   padding:20px;
}

.product > .price {
   background:#88BA33;
   text-align: center;
   padding:20px 0;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   font-size: 18px;
   color:#fff;
   margin:0;
}

.product > .add-to-cart {
    background:#fafafa;
    text-align: center;
    padding:20px 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin:0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your input, but i doubt i can manage HTML since this is CMS online editor :S

Comment: Ah, well that was my fear embedded :) But even CMS editors may have some sort of "html edit mode" so if you feel like taking a walk on the wild side and your editor has that kind of mode, then... Well, just a thought.

But well yes, then you're really only up for opencart users answering.

Comment: well yes there is HTML editor, but just for a few parts, not whole page tho =\ thank you anyway!